# Can I use a hot wire on another panel?

Tags: electrical, wiring, breaker-box

I have a room upstairs that's the size of a small studio apartment. My daughter decided to move back home but my tenant noticed that the room she moved into is tied into their apartment. I went to the panel box and noticed that there is a 12/3 wire in place.

My question is can I take the hot wire going to my kid's room and put it on my panel? Would it be ok with the ground and neutral still plugged into the other panel?

Answer (score 8):

No is your answer.  Move the complete circuit or don't move anything  This can really be a safety concern if one panel is shut down and the neutral and ground are on a live panel, or vice versa.

Comment: To put it another way, 12/3 should go to a duplex breaker where both legs always turn off together.